# Random generating of numbers doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to create a programm that makes sudoku's. But when I try to let the programm place numbers at random spots it doesnt use every position.

I tried to use `rand();` with `srand(time(0));` 
and random number generators from `<random>`.

In the Constructor i use this:

```cpp
mt19937_64 randomGeneratorTmp(time(0));
randomGenerator = randomGeneratorTmp;
uniform_int_distribution<int> numGetterTmp(0, 8);
numGetter = numGetterTmp;
```

While I have `randomGenerator` and `numGetter` variable so i can use them in another function of the sudoku object.
And this is the function where i use the random numbers:

```cpp
bool fillInNumber(int n){
     int placedNums = 0, tries=0;
     int failedTries[9][9];
     for(int dim1=0;dim1<9;dim1++){
         for(int dim2=0;dim2<9;dim2++){
             failedTries[dim1][dim2] = 0;
         }
     }

     while(placedNums<9){
         int dim1 = numGetter(randomGenerator);
         int dim2 = numGetter(randomGenerator);
         if(nums[dim1][dim2]==0){
             if(allowedLocation(n,dim1,dim2)){
                 nums[dim1][dim2] = n;
                 placedNums++;
             } else {
                 failedTries[dim1][dim2]++;
                 tries++;
             }
         }
         if(tries>100000000){
             if(placedNums == 8){
                 cout<< "Number: " << n << endl;
                 cout<< "Placing number: " << placedNums << endl;
                 cout<< "Dim1: " << dim1 << endl;
                 cout<< "Dim2: " << dim2 << endl;
                 printArray(failedTries);
             }
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
}
```

(The array `failedTries` just shows me which positions the program tried.
and most of the fields have been tried millions of times, while others not once)

I think that the random generation just repeats itself before it used every number combination, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you need to fill every position, you should take the set of positions, shuffle it, and fill the positions from their new, random sequence.

Comment: fyi __rand() Considered Harmful__ by STL:  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: @RichardCritten imho that talk is a tiny bit over the top. I mean it is all correct what he says, but when you use a prng without being aware of its limitations then anyhow you are doing something wrong. Also I miss a "`<rand>` considered easy to use" ;)

Comment: Hi new contributor! I'll be gentle. :D Random numbers are tied to the number of spaces you can fill and the range of your randomness. If you have 9 numbers to choose from and range of 1-9. Numbers you will get for that range will be centered around 4.5 +- 2.5 ( or 2 to 7 , with the peak around 4 or 5 ). The same follows for the number of places ( Second and 7th place would be filled often , and the most used place would be 4 or 5. This justifies your issue.

Comment: @Danilo this is maybe true for a normal distribution but in general this is just plain wrong. OP is using a uniform distribution

Comment: Normal / not normal distribution. Permutations increase exponential in size if there are a lot of tries or lot of variables to choose from. The user wants to increase "randomness", if he had 2 choices to chose from, normal or uniform it doesn't matter. So OP, increase the count of data you are searching ( 1-99 ) and then try to find a way to convert it from that range to 1-9.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem.  The behavior you're seeing is correct and expected, there will be lots of duplicates before you see all the values.

Comment: @pjs but should not every of the 81 possibilities be chosen once? (I mean i let the programm try it 100 Million times)

Comment: @SoTBurst i am terribly sorry for this back and forth between me and the user. It isn't ok from our side overtaking your question. Just, i must ask : What kind of randomness do you expect of 100 million times ? I mean you should see some repetition at that count.

Comment: @SoTBurst Full code wasn't provided.  OP states initialization occurs in the constructor, but it's not clear (to me) how often and where this is invoked.  If this code is measuring multiple invocations within the same time tick then it will produce lots of copies of identical results.

Comment: @Danilo no, the problem the programm had/has is, that after those 100 million tries some of the 81 possibilities haven't been 'chosen' once, but the other for example 74 of the possibilties have been choosen about 13 million times.

Comment: @pjs the constructor is used once at the beginning. Or what do you want to know?

Comment: I'd like to see a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Giving us just the function is not sufficient, since we don't know the context in which that function was called.

Comment: @pjs im fine, using the method of ajgryc i made it (and i actually had a bug at another point in my code too)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect random numbers to have an even distribution over your matrix - there's no guarantee they will. That would be like having a routine to randomly generate cards from a deck, and waiting until you see all 52 values - you may wait a very very long time to get every single card.

That's especially true since "random" numbers are actually generated by pseudorandom number generators, which, generally utilize multiplying a very large number and adding an arbitrary constant. Depending on the algorithm, this might cluster in unanticipated ways.

If I may make a suggestion: create an array of all of the possible matrix positions, and then shuffle that array. That's how deck shuffling algorithms are able to guarantee you have all the cards in the deck covered, and it's the same problem you're having.

For a shuffle, generate two random positions in the array and exchange the values - repeat as many times as it takes to get a suitably random result. (Since your array is limited to 9x9, I might shuffle an array of ints 0..80: extract the columns and rows with a /9 and a % 9 for each int).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I actually started to change my program in that way after seeing Scotts command.

Comment: Your description of how PRNGs work applies to LCGs, but is not true in general as you claim.  Also, the coefficients are not arbitrary, they are carefully selected.

Comment: The number of total random attempts to write should be around 81*ln(81) which is under 400, so the total number of failed attempts should be below 400 on average. OP probably has a bug in code.

Comment: @ALX23z thats what i thought. Now i reconstructed it with an array t shuffle and found a couple of bugs so im not sure if one of them made that odd behavior

Comment: @ajgryc standard random engines are good enough to generate mutually independent numbers over 81 outputs. Even if its taken by two sequential tries of 9 inputs. They improved over last 70 years. There was a time when vast physical simulations produced anomalies as a result of random engine faults but in current age, they satisfy a very large number of statistical requirements to be decent. So your post is completely wrong.

Comment: @ALX23z Thanks for keeping me honest on the statistical properties of random number generators. To refine my main point - using an algorithm that is reliant on the properties of your random number generator to determine it's run length (or even to halt) doesn't seem like a good strategy.

Comment: @ajgryc you are wrong on this part. There is a variety of cases when deterministic methods are completely impractical and much slower than the random techniques so you have no choice but to rely on random number techniques. Run-times are in fact usually very stable due to central-limit-theorem. Of course there are ways to mess up usage of random numbers and get unstable or ridiculously large run-times out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple program that should be equivalent to your code, and it works without issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine          engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(0,80);
    std::vector<bool>              vals(81,false);

    int attempts    = 0;
    int trueCount   = 0;
    while(trueCount < 81)
    {
        int newNum = distr(engine);
        if(!vals[newNum])
        {
            vals[newNum] = true;
            trueCount++;
        }

        attempts++;
    }

    std::cout << "attempts: " << attempts;

    return 0;
}
```

Usually it prints around 400 attempts which is the statistical average.

You most likely have a bug in your code. I am not sure where though, as you don't show all of your code.